# Why did GPG replace my keys with someone else's?

Tags: ubuntu, gnupg, linux-mint

Who is [Alexandru Rosianu Bintray](http://aluxian.com) and why is he showing up on my machine?  And where are ***my*** keys!?!?!

After updating a Linux Mint box I could not use `gpg --list-keys` without getting a `permission denied` error.  It was now owned by `root`.  After changing the permissions of my `~/.gnupg` back to me (using `sudo chown -R gdeward.gdeward ~/.gnupg`), the `gpg --list-keys` command works but my keys have been replaced with one key from this [Alexandru](http://aluxian.com/) guy!  See for yourself:

```
gdeward@devwks01: ~/
$ gpg --list-keys
/home/gdeward/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
--------------------------------
pub   4096R/xxxxxxxx 2016-01-29 [expires: 2020-01-29]
uid                  Alexandru Rosianu Bintray &lt;me@aluxian.com&gt;
sub   4096R/xxxxxxxx 2016-01-29 [expires: 2020-01-29]
```

(I masked the key IDs, that were actually shown, from the snippet above.)

**Important:**
I originally built this machine using dotfiles tweaked from [Catalin Maris](http://catalinmaris.com), available [here on GitHub](https://github.com/alrra/dotfiles).  That install caused me to create new keys on GitHub.  **They were listed here prior to me doing an `apt-get upgrade`.**

Searching for a list of GPG packages shows:

```
gdeward@devwks01: ~
$ apt list --installed | grep gpg

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gpgv/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.4.20-1ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed]
libgpg-error0/xenial,now 1.21-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgpgme11/xenial,now 1.6.0-1 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: For some reason gpg lists @aluxian's keys for me too

On Ubuntu however, running `gpg2 --list-keys` shows me my correct keys, I guess mint will be the same?

Answer (score 1):

`Alexandru Rosianu Bintray` is the key I use to sign my [apps uploaded on Bintray](https://bintray.com/aluxian).

I don't know how it ended up in your keyring. The only place where I've published it is on GitHub. See, for instance, [Messenger for Desktop's install README](https://github.com/Aluxian/Messenger-for-Desktop#linux).

Maybe it was added from those dotfiles. Also, I suspect that your other keys could be in another place, ring, or another user's (e.g. root?) folders. (I'm not sure though since I don't use Linux mainly)